# Is firefox refreshing pages by itself ?

Tags: php, html, firefox

I'm wondering something about firefox because of a php code. To make it simple, here is the action. In a page I have a php condition : if action is called, then sql, else show page content.

The thing is, when I'm using it (chrome on a mac), everything run perfectly. But when someone else (Firefox on a pc, tried on two pc), it looks like firefox run the condition (so the sql), refresh the page (even if there is nothing that refresh the page in my code) and re-run the sql because the action is still called. So, the action is called twice (but not more) same for the sql.

I made something with my sql (like verify if the id or something else exists, if yes, don't run the sql). But I don't understand why firefox would refresh the page or run the php twice. Any idea ?

NB : the code is messy so I'd rather not post it here and, as I said, it contains no refresh/redirect line. It's just to know if someone saw that before or is anyone has an idea about this on firefox.

Thanks.

Comment: There are addons for firefox that can do that, but unless one of these is installed firefox does not refresh a site all by itself.

Comment: Note: it is quite possible that the user opens the link with a double click, resulting in two requests.

Comment: `header('Location: ...')` without exit? In any case, unless you're able to post some code this is going to be hard to answer.

Comment: Of-course not firefox doesn't refresh page by itself! unless and until resulting event has fired two times! & yes try to remove other addons from firefox and try!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess my code has a problem yeah because it looks weird. Here is the code (as I said before, really messy. It's an old friend's code that I'll probably rewrite, but I was wondering what was wrong.

The problem is with the lines from 64 to 224. They run two times when I call $_GET['mdq'] or $_GET['absents']

http://www.gerersonaudition.com/affiresa.phps

Comment: When I tried on the pc (with firefox) nothing looks like it refreshing. But I tried to verify the sql records and it records in two different times (like a few seconds).